# npm link, and node: module not found

Tags: node.js, npm

I'd like to install a local package which I frequently use in other packages so that it can be used without relative imports.  After some research, I discovered "npm link".  But I couldn't make it work.

I set up a package "npmtest" with the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "npmtest",
  "description": "minimal package locally linked",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.mjs",
  "bin": {
    "npmtest": "run.mjs"
  }
}
```

An index.mjs with the content:

```
import { sayHello } from "./hello.mjs";

export { sayHello };
```

A hello.mjs with the content:

```
export function sayHello() {
    console.log("hello");
}
```

And finally a run.mjs with the content:

```
import { sayHello } from "./hello.mjs";

sayHello();
```

then I run inside the package `sudo npm link` and the output of `npm ls - g` is

```
/usr/local/lib
├── jsdom@17.0.0
├── npm@8.5.2
└── npmtest@1.0.0 -> ./../../../home/goedel/js/npmtest
```

now I create a package npmtesttest with a package.json:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "npmtest": "^1.0.0"
    }
}
```

and a test.mjs:

```
import { sayHello } from "npmtest";

sayHello();
```

I would now expect

```
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node test.mjs
```

to print "hello" but I get a

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'npmtest' imported from /home/goedel/js/npmtesttest/test.mjs
```

and calling *npmtest* on the command line which I also would expect to print "hello" transforms my mouse cursor to cross hair and frezes the computer :( What I'm doing wrong?